# How do I click a link on Amazon Kindle online?

Tags: amazon, kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

I am reading a book on amazon kindle online.. Their Amazon Kindle for PC is no longer available for download and I don't have it on this computer..

The book I'm reading has some links, but amazon kindle doesn't have any option to copy to clipboard.

It's a technical book and the link  goes to google drive and is for me to download some files, but I can't  click the link. Nothing happens. And I can't copy the link to the clipboard either.